# Integrate the function by substitution method.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac1{ \cos(x-a)\cos(x-b)} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
  Can someone help me to integrate this function by method of substitution.I am not able to start it for possibilities are not coming in my mind.
  If different substitutions are available please let me know?

Comment: Please let me know if question is not readable or understandable.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply top an bottom by $\sin(b-a)$ and then write
$$\sin(b-a)=\sin[(x-a)-(x-b)]=\sin(x-a)\cos(x-b)-\sin(x-b)\cos(x-a).$$

Comment: Which substitution do you make after doing this?

Comment: @user84413 once you do all the steps you will get something like $\int \tan(x-a) \, dx$. For this you need to use $\cos(x-a)=u$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; now I see how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness

Using compound angle formula, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}\sin (b-a) = \sin (x-a) \cos (x-b)-\cos (x-a) \sin (x-b)
\end{aligned}
$$
Dividing the identity by $\cos (x-a) \cos(x-b)$ and integrating gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\sin (b-a)}{\cos (x-a) \cos(x-b)} d x = & \int \frac{\sin (x-a)}{\csc (x-a)} d x-\int \frac{\sin (x-b)}{\cos (x-b)} d x \\
= & -\ln |\cos (x-a)|+\ln |\cos (x-b)|+c \\
= & \ln \left|\frac{\cos (x-b)}{\cos (x-a)}\right|+c
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\int \frac{d x}{\cos (x-a) \cos(x-b)}=\csc (b-a) \ln \left|\frac{\cos (x-b)}{\cos (x-a)}\right|+C
$$